# There is a sort of limit in "New List(Of String)"?

Tags: vb.net, string, list

I made program witch colors different part of text ( like Notepad++) but i have problem.

this is a part of code, in **Class1**

```vb
Public Shared Function get_c_html()
    Dim html_words As New List(Of String) From {"<html>", "<title>", "<b>" _
    , "</b>", "<u>", "</u>", "<i>", "</i>", "<sub>", "</sub>", "<sup>", "</sup>", "<a href" _
    , "</a>", "<body>", "</body>", "<head>", "</head>", "</font>", "<font>", "<div", "</div", "<title>" _
    , "</title>", "<img", "/>", "<link", "<br>", "<ul>", "</ul>", "<li>", "</li>" _
    , "<table>", "</table>", "<tr>", "</tr>", "<td>", "</td>", "<meta>", "</meta>" _
    , "meta", "<background>"}
    Dim icountMatch As Integer = 0
    For Each blue As String In html_words
        icountMatch = HighlightWords(Form1.rchtml, blue, Color.Blue)
    Next
    Return 0
End Function
```

Program works properly and highlight text, but if i add "/html" in html_words the program did not starts.

I tryed to add anoter Public shared Function but give me same "*error*".

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger to see at which point execution stops/hangs?

Comment: yes but nothing appears, unfortunately

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing appears"?  Do you see the yellow highlight and can you step through the code line by line?  Also, check the output window and see if there is anything displayed there.

Answer (score 0):

> Program works properly and highlight text, but if i add "/html" in html_words the program did not starts.

The list statement is working fine.  The problem is most likely the HighlightWords function.

On a side note if you're not going to return a meaningful value you should use a Sub instead of a function

Comment: I'd try with </html> and doesen't works, i really don't know where the problem is

Comment: Add the code for the HighlightWords function to your original post so we can help you find the problem.